# Multiple nested includes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have four models, Groups, Users, Posts and Comments in my Rails 3 app. The relation is:

```
Groups has_many Users
Users has_many Posts
Posts has_many Comments
```

(and all with belongs_to in the other direction)

How do I get all comments that belongs to a group.id in one query?
I can not stop thinking of using multiple includes() (but without success so far) like

```
comments = Comment.includes(:Post).includes(:User).includes(:Group).where("groups.id IS ?", group.id)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `eager_load` method:

```
comments = Comment.eager_load(post: {user: :group}).where('groups.id = ?', group.id)
```

You can find more info about this type of queries in this [blog post](http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/).

Comment: There’s not really any reason to use `eager_load` over `includes` here, and it may change the results depending on the conditions.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall how it can change results depending on the conditions?

Comment: @MarekLipka But it is still allowed in Rails 4 right?

Comment: @Pavan yes, it's still allowed.

Comment: Whoops, I think I was thinking of `preload`. Also `includes` itself isn’t deprecated AFAIK, only certain uses of it.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall of course, you're right, what's deprecated in use of `includes` similar to `eager_load` without listing referenced tables.

Comment: @Marek Lipka Thanks, works great with both, eager_load and includes.

Answer (score 10):

You Can still do with includes

```
comments = Comment.includes(post: {user: :group}).where('groups.id = ?', group.id)
```

See this [**topic**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) in **`Rails 4.1`** Guides